# does affine transformation change neighbourhood

Tags: affinetransform

I have a set of 100 points.
I am considering 4 closest neighbour of each point.
Using three (non-collinear) points as basis among these four, I get affine coordinate of the fourth point.
This way I create database for 100 points.
There are 100 x <sup>4</sup>C<sub>3</sub> x 3 records. Each having an affine coordinate.
Now, I did affine transformation on all 100 points.
Specifically ,
If a point is (x,y)
It becomes new_x = x+2y+5
It becomes new_y = 3x+4y+6
I have observed that closest neighbours of all points got changed.
Actually some points had 1 or 2 neighbours as before, but rest changed.
As a result affine coordinate matching did not work.
Note that I am calculating closest neighbour using euclidean distance i.e sqrt((x<sub>2</sub>-x<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup>+(y<sub>2</sub>-y<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup>).
When I think about affine transformation - I feel rotation,scaling and translation won't change neighbours but shearing maybe can.
Is my transformation not affine ?
Can you suggest a better way to get neighbours ?
Thanks.

Comment: Shearing is an affine transformation.

Comment: https://in.mathworks.com/discovery/affine-transformation.html says so